# Creating a MYSQL view with UNION ALL

Tags: mysql

Iam trying to join two queries by using UNION ALL and trying to create a MYSQL DB view. IS this the correct way of showing this? The only difference between this two query is a subquery WHERE Condition and the Main WHERE condition, rest both queries are same. I wanted to know if its the correct way of doing this, or is there any alternate way in achieving this. My query/view is as follows.

```
create or replace view view_bank_guarantee as

SELECT
view_sales_report.tender_id,
view_sales_report.customer_code,
com_payments.bank_ref_no,

(select
com_receipts.rec_date_of_credit
FROM com_receipts
WHERE com_receipts.rec_main_section ='SBG Cancellation' AND view_sales_report.tender_id = com_receipts.tender_id
) AS BGClosedOn

FROM com_payments
LEFT OUTER JOIN view_sales_report ON com_payments.tender_id = view_sales_report.tender_id AND com_payments.main_section ='Bank Guarantee SD'
LEFT OUTER JOIN com_receipts ON com_payments.tender_id = com_receipts.tender_id
GROUP BY view_sales_report.tender_id
HAVING BGClosedOn IS NULL AND (view_sales_report.tender_id !='') 

UNION ALL  

SELECT 
view_sales_report.tender_id,
view_sales_report.customer_code,
com_payments.bank_ref_no,

(select
com_receipts.rec_date_of_credit
FROM com_receipts
WHERE com_receipts.rec_main_section ='PBG Cancellation' AND view_sales_report.tender_id = com_receipts.tender_id
) AS BGClosedOn

FROM com_payments
LEFT OUTER JOIN view_sales_report ON com_payments.tender_id = view_sales_report.tender_id AND com_payments.main_section ='Bank Guarantee PBG'
LEFT OUTER JOIN com_receipts ON com_payments.tender_id = com_receipts.tender_id
GROUP BY view_sales_report.tender_id
HAVING BGClosedOn IS NULL AND (view_sales_report.tender_id !='')
```

Comment: No Replies. So i think its a wrong question.

Comment: `WHERE rec_main_section IN('SBG Cancellation',PBG Cancellation')` ?

Comment: Thank you, i will start with ur suggestion. Let me try.